# Microsoft Bot Framework - Send Message to Channel from Bot programmatically

Tags: azure, botframework

I have a Bot implemented in my app which has below endpoint. However, I have another endpoint in my app which should invoke the Bot to send a message to a channel based on data received. How do I create the context with required parameters and then invoke Bot the programmatically (e.g. call bot.run(context))?

```
app.post('/api/messages', async (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        await bot.run(context);
    });
});
```

I tried creating context object to send to bot.run(context) however its not working and need an example on how to setup the context object.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [proactive messaging](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages)?